# VB.net Avoid Non-Visible gridview rows with StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, csv, gridview, stringbuilder, visible

My current gridview has various hidden rows however; when I copy the rows into a csv file it shows the hidden rows as empty rows. I tried to by pass the empty rows with line `If (DisplaySup.Rows(i).Visible = True)` however; the empty rows still show up. Is there a workaround for this?

```
Protected Sub SheetSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SheetSave.Click

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=gvtocsv.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"
    Dim sBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For index As Integer = 1 To DisplaySuppliers.Columns.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(DisplaySuppliers.Columns(index).HeaderText + ","c)
    Next
    sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    For i As Integer = 1 To DisplaySup.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 1 To DisplaySup.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            If (DisplaySup.Rows(i).Visible = True) Then
                sBuilder.Append(DisplaySup.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "").Replace("&nbsp;", "") + ",")
            End If
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Comment: NB. You arnt compliant with this RFC - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding newlines regardless - you need to move that inside the check!

Example:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To DisplaySup.Rows.Count - 1
    If (DisplaySup.Rows(i).Visible = True) Then
        For k As Integer = 1 To DisplaySup.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1                
            sBuilder.Append(DisplaySup.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "").Replace("&nbsp;", "") + ",")              
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    End If        
Next
```

Comment: Oh wow. I thought by the check being inside would have worked. My mindset was a little off but I am so relieved that my coding in itself was going to work :) Thank you for helping me figure out my issue